# Angular4, Azure Active Directory and WebApi2 backend with bearer token not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin, ninject, azure-active-directory

I have an Angular4 client which handles authentication with AAD using ADAL.js.
After signing in I can successfully see my username as well as my JWT token.

Now I want to connect to a WebApi2 service. I am passing the Token as bearer token in the headers, but for some reason I keep getting a **401 "Authorization has been denied"** from my API.

**Angular4 client**

```
headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.adalService.accessToken);
```

**Request header**
[image: Request header]

**Response header**
[image: Response header]

**Startup.cs**

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
        ConfigureNinject(app);
    }
}
```

**Startup.Auth.cs**

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"],
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"],
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Startup.Ninject.cs**

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureNinject(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var kernel = CreateKernel();
        app.UseNinjectMiddleware(() => kernel).UseNinjectWebApi(WebApiConfig.GetConfiguration());

        return kernel;
    }

    private static IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
        kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

        RegisterServices(kernel);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel);
        return kernel;
    }

    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        // some bindings here
    }
}
```

**UsersController.cs**

```
public class UsersController : ApiController
{
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get
    {
        return Ok("test");
    }
}
```

**UPDATE: RESOLUTION**
As pointed out by Navya Canumalla in the comments, the clientId value used in adal.js and ida:Audience in Web.config need to be the same value. This was not the case here. I have corrected that and it works as expected now.

Comment: What is the ida:Audience you are setting in the ConfigurationManager? 
It has to be the same value as the aud claim in the token. You can check the claims in the token by visiting https://jwt.ms

Comment: That was indeed the issue! The two tutorials I followed for Angular and WebApi apparently had different views on what to enter as Audience. Thank you very much! I will update my question with the answer in hope that it might help anyone in the future.